# HC-08 - RPI 3 - Can read but can't write

Tags: python, bluetooth, serial

I use a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I have a Bluetooth HC-08 module.

I would like to be able to send and receive data. I use the port /dev/ttyS0 and I changed the file /boot/config.txt for "enable_uart=1"

I connected the RX pin of the module to pin 8 of the RPI and the TX pin to pin 10. ( TX -> RX / RX -> TX)

To test, I use a mobile application, LightBlue. I can read the data I send from the application but I can't write.

I also changed parameters in raspi-config, Interface Options / Serial -> No -> Yes

Here's my test code :

```
import time
import serial

print "Starting program"

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600,
                    parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
                    stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                    bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
                    )
time.sleep(1)
try:
    ser.write('Hello World\r\n')
    ser.write('Serial Communication Using Raspberry Pi\r\n')
    ser.write('By: Embedded Laboratory\r\n')
    print 'Data Echo Mode Enabled'
    while True:
        if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            data = ser.read()
            print data

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Exiting Program"

except:
    print "Error Occurs, Exiting Program"

finally:
    ser.close()
    pass
```

I don't know why I can read but not write data ... Do I miss something ?

Some help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The RX pin on my module was down. I changed Bluetooth module to a new one. And I could write again.

I share my test code if it can help someone

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# serial_read.py

import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600)

try:
  while True:
    if ser.inWaiting() > 0:
      data = ser.readline()
      print(data)
except KeyboardInterrup:
  print "Exiting program"
except:
  print "Error occurs"
finally:
  ser.close()
  pass


#!/usr/bin/env python
# serial_write.py

import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600)

counter = 0

try:
  while True:
    ser.write('Write counter: %d \n'%(counter))
    time.sleep(1)
    counter++
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  print "Exiting program"
except:
  print "Error occurs"
finally:
  ser.close()
  pass
```